# Quais técnicas permitem obter um benchmark confiável de desempenho de uma função ou programa single-thread?

Tags: c, thread, benchmark

Fala-se que calcular somente o delta entre dois instantes (início e fim de execução de um trecho de código), em mili- ou nanossegundos, não é 100% confiável para se fazer um benchmark do desempenho na execução desse código.

De fato, estando uma thread concorrendo com outras (não relacionadas ao que está sendo testado) pelo tempo de CPU e sendo todas escalonadas de acordo com certos critérios, esse valor acaba ficando impreciso.

Embora isso possa ser mitigado repetindo-se o teste várias vezes e tirando-se uma média, qual seria uma maneira mais garantida de se calcular a eficiência de um algoritmo *single-thread*? Os sistemas operacionais chegam a coletar essa informação do tempo por thread em execução, sem considerar o que foi gasto em outros *time slices*?

A ferramenta `time` do GNU/Linux (com documentação acessível através do comando `man time`, e que pode ser usada com a intenção de avaliar a eficiência de programas) parece sugerir que sim. Alguns dos seus parâmetros:

```
E      Elapsed real (wall clock) time used by the process, in
                 [hours:]minutes:seconds.

(...)

S      Total number of CPU-seconds used by the system on behalf
                 of the process (in kernel mode), in seconds.
U      Total number of CPU-seconds that the process used
                 directly (in user mode), in seconds.
```

Estou adicionando a tag [c](/questions/tagged/c) que, acredito, vai dar uma base para entender benchmarks feitas em outras linguagens ou de outras maneiras, mas ela não é necessariamente um requisito. Pode-se falar, portanto, em benchmark em linguagens de script se for o caso.

Tenho expectativa de receber uma resposta agnóstica ao sistema operacional, porém uma que se restrinja a sistemas *Unix-like* (ou mesmo só Linux) seria satisfatória também, só precisaria ajustar as *tags* da pergunta.

Pergunto sobre programas com uma única *thread*, mas servem também técnicas para benchmark de funções.

Comment: Apenas para complementar, o Windows tem uma ferramenta no PowerShell com o mesmo propósito do `time` no GNU/Linux, mas funciona de forma diferente. Algumas informações estão [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-do-i-measure-execution-time-of-a-command-on-the-windows-command-line).

Comment: @RuanMontelo Parece que as respostas não medem tempo de CPU (_CPU time_), só _wall clock time_, então caem no problema da imprecisão.

Comment: A única forma que imagino para chegar neste nível de precisão, seria: 1) setar a [afinidade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) da *thread/processo* para evitar possíveis influências de cache em uma eventual mudança de contexto (durante o teste); e 2) setar a prioridade do processo no [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) para tempo real (*real time*) no nível administrador ou root.

Comment: Quanto ao item 2, recomendo utilizá-lo somente no trecho de código testado, supondo que ele só utilize rotinas do processador e não dependa de nenhum tipo de operação de IO, e que você tenha certeza absoluta e conhecimento suficiente do que está testando (talvez, os SOs atuais não necessitem mais deste cuidado extremo). Possivelmente, alguém com maior experiência tenha uma técnica melhor para indicar.